# Trapping misformatted paths to Redirect to 404 instead of returning 403

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

Owing to an error long ago our company web site has been serving image URLs containing a significant amount of white space.

E.g.

```
http://www.example.com/                      /assets/ProductPhotos/image.png
```

Somehow, browsers have handled this (presumably by stripping out the whitespace) and nobody noticed the problem.

We have now fixed the problem, but crawlers that aren't being so intelligent have indexed this URL and come back trying to find it again.

This results in a message in the error log:

> [core:error] [pid 5040:tid 1068] (20024)The given path is misformatted
> or contained invalid characters: [client 192.168.128.4:38656] AH00127:
> Cannot map GET
> /%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/assets/ProductPhotos/image.png HTTP/1.1 to file

We're seeing a lot of these.

Apache returns a `403 Forbidden`, the crawler goes away and tries again a few days later.

I'd like to intercept these requests and return a `404 Not Found`, or even a `410 Gone`, or maybe just a `400 Bad Request` in the hope that this will persuade these crawlers not to bother us.

However, I haven't found a way to recognise the bad URL.

Currently, I have

```
#Trap URLs with occurrences of /<22 spaces>/ and redirect to a 404
<if "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/(%20|\s)+/#">

redirect 404 /
</if>
```

in my .htaccess file, but Apache still returns `403 Forbidden`. It's as though Apache has parsed the URL, decided it's bad, and returned a response, all before .htaccess gets a look in.

(I could put this in a vHost file but that would involve restarting the live server. Not popular here!)

Is there a way to pick these bad URLs up and handle them without relying on Apache's default behaviour?

**Update:**

Server: Apache 2.4.12, Windows.

I've set up a virgin vHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "c:/***********/websites/webtest">
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require ip 192.168.0.0/21 192.168.131.0/24
        </RequireAll>
    </Directory>
    
    DocumentRoot "c:/*************/websites/webtest"
    ServerName webtest.*************
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    CustomLog "|./bin/rotatelogs.exe -l C:/***********/apache24/logs/webtest.access.%y%m%d.log 86400" combined
    ErrorLog "|./bin/rotatelogs.exe -l C:/***********/apache24/logs/webtest.error.%y%m%d.log 86400"

    SetEnv WEBSITE_NAME webtest.***********
</VirtualHost>
```

It has one folder with a handful of files, and this `ht.conf` file (same as above) The access file name is overridden from `.htaccess` in the defaults section. References to `.htaccess` can be taken to mean `ht.conf` everywhere.

```
#Trap URLs with occurrences of /<22 spaces>/ and redirect to a 404
<if "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/(%20|\s)+/#">

redirect 404 /
</if>
```

It also includes the folder and file `assets/f22.jpg`, relative to the document root.

Browsing to `http://webtest.**********/assets/f22.jpg` returns the image correctly

Browsing to `http://webtest.**********/        /assets/f22.jpg` returns

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / /assets/f22.jpg on this server.the image correctly
```

Comment: Would it really involve restarting the server? Apache httpd has supported live configuration reload ("graceful restart") for quite a while, as do other production webservers.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? Has anything changed on the server that you are aware of? By "fixing the problem" have you simply removed the erroneous spaces from the generated URL in the HTML source? And these errors have only started appearing since you "fixed the problem"?

Comment: @user1686 I wasn't aware of that - I haven't done a lot with Apache. I'll look into it, but unless the fix involves a vHost it's a bit of a side issue.

Comment: @MrWhite The problem we fixed was the original web site sending the bad URLs. The probem we have now is that we don't seem to be able to persuade the bots that have crawled those bad URLs to stop using them. That's why I want to change the return code to something more meaningful. As far as I can tell, the problem has existed almost as long as the bad URLs, but it's impossible to know. Nobody has looked at the logs for (literally) years. It's taken me several weeks of fixing to get the problems to manageable levels. This is only the most intractable.

Comment: After writing up the update I posted above, it occurs to me that the bad URL is actually a different path from the valid equivalent. There may be a `<Directory>` entry in the configuration section that plays a role here.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to resolve this in `.htaccess` is "too late". As you stated, this all happens "before .htaccess gets a look in".

`.htaccess` files (and `<Directory>` containers) are only processed *after* the request has been mapped to the filesystem. As noted in the error message: "Cannot map ... to file", the error/response is seemingly being triggered at the time (or before) the request is being mapped to the filesystem.

A "403 Forbidden" response is not a "normal" response for such a request, so *something* would seem to be forcibly returning this response. Ordinarily, I would expect Apache to return a regular 404 for such a request. If the URL-path was wholly "invalid" then Apache should respond with a "400 Bad Request" (again, something which cannot be overridden in `.htaccess`).

So, this response would seem to be triggered earlier in server config. Ordinarily you should find out where/why Apache is serving this response. (An additional security module like mod_security perhaps?) And modify this accordingly, rather than try to "override" it. However, since a 403 is being triggered, you could perhaps define a custom 403 `ErrorDocument` (again, in the server config, *not* `.htaccess`) in which you analyse the request and override accordingly.

> Somehow, browsers have handled this (presumably by stripping out the whitespace) and nobody noticed the problem.

The "browser" would not have stripped out the whitespace. The browser would have (automatically) URL-encoded the *spaces* as `%20` (if they were not explicitly URL-encoded in the HTML source). Nothing has changed in this respect at the browser end AFAIK.

So, it would seem that your *server* previously handled these requests and something has since changed on your server that now results in these requests being block. OR, as it transpires, these malformed URLs never worked and nobody noticed the missing image(s) or looked at the logs! (?)

---

**UPDATE:** Windows and Linux are likely to behave differently in this respect. Windows has additional restrictions with regards to the filesystem, that doesn't necessarily affect Linux systems in the same way. (It's unusual to have Apache running on Windows in a production environment.)

Instead of using an Apache `<If>` expression (which is *merged* late), I would tend to use mod_rewrite instead (which is processed early). Try the following directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (not in a `<Directory>` section):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Serve a "410 Gone" for any URL that starts with "spaces"
RewriteRule ^/\s - [G]
```

Alternatively, 301 redirect such requests to the "correct" URL:

```
# Redirect to remove the "spaces"
RewriteRule ^/\s+(/.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

The mod_rewrite directives in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context are processed *before* the request is mapped to the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll go back to the vHost configuration, and the `.htaccess` file in the target folders and see what I can find. I've spent a lot of time recently working in those areas but I'm fairly sure that the 403 issue predates my involvement.

Comment: @AristotleO Yes, I think the 403 has probably always existed and has just gone unnoticed.  (I don't see any correlation with the URL being "fixed".) I've updated my answer with a possible solution, that would need to go in the vHost container.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It'll be a couple of days before I can get back to this. I'll post something when I've tried it.